# Linux `time` command in hour format

Tags: linux, time

Linux `time` command will produce the output in minute and second format.
Is it possible to change it to hour format?

```
[user@Linux ~]$ time ./script.sh

real    394m30.145s
user    388m20.129s
sys     16m16.255s
[user@Linux ~]$
```

It would be nice if the output can be formatted like this

```
[user@Linux ~]$ time ./script.sh

real    6 Hours 34 Minutes 30.145s
user    6 Hours 28 Minutes 20.129s
sys     16m16.255s
[user@Linux ~]$
```

Comment: The question is about the `time` command on _Linux_, but for bypassers it might be interesting what other systems have to offer. If one is on _FreeBSD_ there has been an `-h` option for human-friendly output around for more than [two decades](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/commit/ea257bd5544f0d72af9f801d885f7c0cdfc8c126) that shows the time in hours, minutes and days.

Comment: And while the current version of _NetBSD_ `time` has an `-f` option similiar to Linux, `time` on _macOS_ up to [release 11](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/blob/shell_cmds-216.60.1/time/time.c) was a slightly patched NetBSD `time` [from the 1990s](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/f448bbbefe551f64ccaef0504d4c1fd99699e55f/usr.bin/time/time.c) which did not yet support the option. However as of [macOS 12](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/blob/shell_cmds-234/time/time.c) some variant of FreeBSD `time` is used, so the `-h` is available there also now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/usr/bin/time` instead as I doubt if the shell `time` keyword has formatting options.

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%E" ./script.sh
```

Comment: The `time` keyword does have formatting options, albeit *very* limited. See [`TIMEFORMAT` in Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables).

Comment: @muru, thanks but it didn't work

`user@Linux:~$ /usr/bin/time "%E%" ./script.sh
/usr/bin/time: cannot run %E%: No such file or directory
Command exited with non-zero status 127
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1184maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+27minor)pagefaults 0swaps
user@Linux:~$ `

Comment: @CharlotteRussell that's αғsнιη's answer, and it has `-f "%E"`. Note the `-f`.